# socket hanging and node crashing

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, mongodb

I have a node app that posts data to remote apis and fetches the responses. It works fine but at times the node server crashes and generates the following errror:

```
 events.js:71
throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1264:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1315:23)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I googled and found that it happens due to some timeout thing but i am not really sure as to how to overcome this.
Here is the required code in my server.js:

```
if(request.body.company=="CQ")
    {
        var postData={firstName:request.body.firstname,lastName:request.body.lastname,Email:request.body.email,DayPhoneNumber:request.body.daytimePhone,Address1:request.body.addressOne,city:request.body.city,state:request.body.State,postalCode:request.body.zip,AreaOfIntrest:request.body.areaOfInterest,VendorLocationId:"38404",Notes:request.body.Notes,GraduationYear:request.body.graduationYear,AffiliateLocationId:"12345",LocationId:"12345",CampaignId:"12345"};

        var options={hostname:'webservices.someapi.com', path:'/ILM/Default.ashx?'+qs.stringify(postData), method:'GET'};

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {

        edModel.find({$and:[{daytimePhone:request.body.daytimePhone},{company:"CQ"}]},function(err,count){
        if(count.length==0)
        {
                var sr='RESPONSE: ' + chunk;
                if(sr.indexOf('status="Error"')==-1)
                {
                    request.body.leadid=sr;
                    var sr=sr.slice(sr.indexOf("leadid"));
                    sr=sr.slice(0,sr.indexOf(">"));

                    edDoc=new edModel(request.body);
                    edDoc.save();       
                    response.send({response:sr});
                }
                else
                {
                    response.send({response:sr});
                }
        }
        else
        {
            response.send({response:"<span style='color:red'>Duplicate Lead.<br> A lead with this number already exists in our database</span>"});
        }

    });


        });

        });

        // write data to request body
        req.write('data\n');
        req.end();
    }
```

I have several such if else conditions in the server.js file.

Answer (score 0):

in node 0.8.20 there was a bug about that problem. try using http.get instead of http.request. or just dont use 0.8.20 if you use that version.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this bug for future reference?